# Explanation of this constraint

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, constraints

I am doing an exercise for a Linear Programming Problem where a business is trying to maximise their profits based on the sale of armchairs and sofas.

In the question it is stated that market research has shown that between 4 to 9 armchairs should be held in stock for each 3 sofas held in stock.

$x=$armchairs and $y=$sofas

The armchair/sofa constraint given in the question is $4y\leq3x\leq9y$

Am I misunderstanding this completely or should the constraint not be $4x\leq3y\leq9x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find an easy way to think of this is to plug in real numbers and see if it works.
Say we have 3 sofas. Let's use your equation.
4x<3y<9x -> 4x<9<9x

This equation implies that we should have between 1 and 9/4ths of a armchair. What it SHOULD say is that we should have between 4 and 9.
If we try the correct equation, we see that it does actually work.

4y<3x<9y -> 12<3x<27

4 < x < 9

This confusing need to switch variables happens a lot. 
Consider if I could buy 2 tacos for a dollar.
At first glance, it may seem you can say

2*number of tacos = cost.

But plug in 1 taco, and you are paying 2 dollars. The equation actually reads "The cost equals twice the numbers of tacos bought."
Moral of the story: check your equations carefully when interpreting!